# mysql cur.execute() read in unicode characters error

Tags: python, jdbc, unicode, string-formatting, teradata

my code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
connection = jaydebeapi.connect(#my connection params) #Path to JDBC Driver
cur = connection.cursor()
country='US'
mylist = ［'你好'，'我是明']
```

this is my query string:

```
    myquery="""create table mytable as (
    select * from table1 where country='%s' 
    and terms like any ('%s');""" % (country, "', '".join(mylist))

    cur.execute(myquery)
```

When i do: 
`cur.execute(myquery)`
i get the error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 301: ordinal not in range(128)`

even though `print myquery`
returns the strings in mylist just fine.

How can i encode the query terms within the `cur.execute()`?

Comment: `cur.execute(myquery, (country, "', '".join(mylist)))`; and remove the `% (country, "', '".join(mylist))` from the previous line.

Comment: it didnt work. i got the error: `Parameter index value 1 is outside the valid range of 1 through 0`

Answer (score 0):

found my answer - have to decode each string in mylist during string formatting:

```
  myquery="""create table mytable as (
    select * from table1 where country='%s' 
    and terms like any ('%s');""" % (country, "', '".join([i.decode('utf-8') for i in mylist]))
```